# How to link multiple images in sequence together using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to link a series of images together I know the basic HTML Code for linking 1 image to another would be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML Image as link</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <a href="Imagelink1">
         <img alt="" src="Imagelink2"
         
         >
      </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

But I'm trying to continue the chain from Imagelink2 to Imagelink3 to Imagelink4 and so on.
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: if you consider JS, don't add an anchor as a link but add an eventListener and listen to click event to redirect to a certain elements

Comment: @tacoshy Okay, I am not very familiar with that, unfortunately. Are there any references you could link to me?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to do that. You have to create a link for each image.

Example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML Image as link</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <a href="Imagelink1">
         <img src="Imagelink1" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="Imagelink2">
         <img src="Imagelink2" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="Imagelink3">
         <img src="Imagelink3" alt="">
      </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, so even when creating a link for each one there is no way to chain them together so I can move through them in order individually? Is there another method or tool I could use to achieve this with the images I am using? They are housed in WordPress.

Comment: Could you specify with an example?

Comment: Sorry, so like before is there another method where I can click through a series of images 1 by 1.  Image 1 >User clicks to get to> Image 2 >User clicks to get to> Image 3.

Comment: I suppose that you want something like anchors between images, that when you click on the first image, this will move to the second image, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>HTML Image as link</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <a href="#img2">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-anjana-c-674010.jpg&fm=jpg" id="img1" alt="" />
      </a>


      <a href="#img3">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" id="img2" alt="" />
      </a>


      <a href="#img1">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/flowers-276014__340.jpg" id="img3" alt="" />
      </a>
    </body>

    </html>
```